# i want to convert an array created by pressing on buttons to json?

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, json, symfony

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery example</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">



</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1>STORYBOARD</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var i=0;
var counter = 0;
var counter1 =0;
var counter2 =0;
var counter3 =0;
var counter4 =0;
var inputs = new Array();
var $type,$name, $label;


$("#txt").click(function(){
counter++;

var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name:'text'+counter, value:'text'+counter,id:'tx' + counter}).addClass("text" + counter);
var $del = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', name:'btn1',value:'x',id:'bx'+ counter }).addClass("btn" + counter);

$("#holder").append($ctrl);
$("#holder").append($del);

inputs.push(['text','text'+counter,'tx'+counter]);
i++;


$("#bx" + counter ).click(function () {
$("#tx" + counter).remove();
$("#bx" + counter).remove();
counter --;
});
});

$("#chk").click(function(){
counter1 ++;
var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'checkbox', name:'checkbox'+counter1, id:'ck' + counter1}).addClass("chk");
var $del = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', name:'btn1',value:'x',id:'bx1' +counter1}).addClass("btn" + counter1);
$("#holder").append($ctrl);
$("#holder").append($del);
inputs.push(['checkbox','checkbox'+counter1,'ck'+counter1]);
i++;

$("#bx1" + counter1 ).click(function () {
$("#ck" + counter1).remove();
$("#bx1" + counter1).remove();
counter1 --;
});
});

$("#rad").click(function(){
counter2 ++;
var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'radio', name:'radio' +counter2, id:'rd' + counter2}).addClass("rad");
var $del = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', name:'btn1',value:'x',id:'bx2' +counter2}).addClass("btn" +counter2);
$("#holder").append($ctrl);
$("#holder").append($del);

inputs.push(['radio','radio'+counter2,'rd'+counter2]);
i++;

$("#bx2" + counter2 ).click(function () {
$("#rd" + counter2).remove();
$("#bx2" + counter2).remove();
counter2 --;
});
});

$("#btn").click(function(){
counter3 ++;
var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', name:'button' +counter3,value:'Button', id:'bt' + counter3 }).addClass("btn");
var $del = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', name:'btn1',value:'x', id:'bx3' +counter3}).addClass("btn" +counter3);
$("#holder").append($ctrl);
$("#holder").append($del);

inputs.push(['button','button'+counter3,'bt'+counter3]);
i++;
```

the input i created when the user press on a button
the it increments

```
$("#bx3" + counter3 ).click(function () {
$("#bt" + counter3).remove();
$("#bx3" + counter3).remove();
counter3 --;

});
});


});

var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[1].lastName;
</script>
</head><body>
<div>
 <div style="display:inline">
<input type="button" id="txt" value="Add TextBox" style="" /><br>
<input type="button" id="chk" value="Add CheckBox" style="" /><br>
<input type="button" id="rad" value="Add Radio" style="" /><br>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Add Button" style="" /><br>

</div>
<div id="holder">
</div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

i want to convert the array inputs[] to json data to send them to the server that is writen in php and to stock the data from the array in a databse using sql 
**convert array to json file**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in search of   [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify (inputs);
```

Comment: how can i check that  JSON.stringify works? and where should i put it in the code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

and use console.log(someArray) to debug to have a look if it stringifies correctly. 
if you are using jQuery, send it via $.ajax({}).

Serverside just have a look at $_REQUEST/$_POST array.

Comment: how can i send the array to the server using ajax? note:the server is the local host wamp

Comment: You should probably beak this up into multiple questions instead of adding more in the comments.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

just use a form and add name to your fields :

```
<form id="myform">
<div style="display:inline">
<input type="button" id="txt" value="Add TextBox" name="chk[]" style="" /><br>
<input type="button" id="chk" value="Add CheckBox" name="chk[]" style="" /><br>
<input type="button" id="rad" value="Add Radio" name="chk[]" style="" /><br>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Add Button" name="chk[]" style="" /><br>
</form>
</div>
```

then in your js script use form.serialize() method to get your form data and just send it like it is to your server it will be parsed to an array automatically

Comment: the objective of my program is to add buttons and text fields dynamically and fill array with the types name and ids of every inputs